# Cannot read .7z file in Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab to create a deep learning model, and I face an issue when I run this code at the **first time**.

```
!p7zip -d filename.7z
```

I get the following message:

```
/usr/bin/p7zip: cannot read filename.7z
```

**But** when I re-run the same cell again, the code works.

Do you know what is the reason of this issue?

Comment: I have faced the same problem :/

Comment: Can you share a notebook that reproduces the problem? There isn't enough information in your question to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to specify path before the file name 
in my case

```
!mkdir ~/data
!cd ~/data
!mkdir planet
!cd planet

# -c: competition name
# -f: which file you want to download
# -p: path to where the file should be saved
!kaggle competitions download -c planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space -f train-jpg.tar.7z -p ~/data/planet/

# Unzip the 7zip files
# -d: which file to un7zip
!p7zip -d ~/data/planet/test-jpg.tar.7z
```